# CSS: Positioning items with top-margin

Tags: html, css

**ETA: Thanks for all the help, everyone! These all worked beautifully. Thanks so much for your time!**

I'm coding a newsletter (live preview [here](http://www.orangejuicediaries.com/NewLeafNewsletter/untitled.html) and my goal for it [here](http://www.orangejuicediaries.com/NLNewsletterv2wHeaders.png)) and am trying to get the navigation buttons ('Join Meet Learn Support') to sit about halfway down the logo. When I try top-margin in the navButtons class I'm not seeing any success. I suspect it's a display issue, but I'm not sure --- changing from inline to inline-block didn't really help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>The Leaflet</title>

<style>


div
{
    display: inline;
}

a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
p
{
    text-align:left;
    margin-left: 130px;
    margin-right: 130px;
    max-width: 600px;

}

#logo /* This sets the width for the New Leaf logo at the top. This should not change.*/
{
    position:relative;
}

#navButtons
{
 position:relative;
 right:-240px;
}

#announcementImage
{
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-right: 120px;
}


a.joinButton
{
    margin-left:40%;
    color:white;
    background-color: #f7853e;
    font-size: 30px;

}

a.navButton
{
    color:#494541;
    font-size: 22px;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="logo"> <! --- Sets up the logo --->
<img src ="images/NLNewsletterLogo.png">
</div>

<div id="nav buttons"> <! --- Navigation Bar--->
<a class = "joinButton" href="url">Join</a>
<a class = "navButton" href="url">  Meet  </a>
<a class = "navButton" href="url">Learn  </a>
<a class = "navButton" href="url">Support  </a>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div id ="announcementImage"><! --- Lead Image-->
<img src="images/announcementGraphic.png">
</div>

<div id = "announcementText">
<p>Thrive Week is in full swing here at the Leaf. So far, we've had Sharon Perry, head of the State
College Area School District Career Center, help participants identify which of 34 traits,
including the special quality of woo, are strengths they employ in various settings so they can
work smarter. Then Anna Gokieli, owner of Tru Meditation and Yoga, got us staying present and 
peaceful even in situations that often trigger stress. Will Snyder brought it home last night by 
showing how making art and making money don't have to conflict.

Have a comment on a workshop you've attended or a session you'd like to see in our remaining 
Design and Launch weeks? Galen would love to hear from you!</p>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `#logo{vertical-align: middle}`? Is that what your looking for?

Comment: Agreeing with @Krii.  `vertical-align:middle` will work in this case (used on `#logo`) because both `#logo` and `id="nav buttons"` (invalid ID btw.  See [the w3c documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)) are `inline` or `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what your looking for is:

```css
#logo {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#nav {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: vertical-align on the logo is the key.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `bottom` of something like 60px to `div` with id `nav buttons`.

Since this element is `position: relative`, it's placement can be controlled with `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`, like so:

```
#nav#buttons {
    bottom: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Floating the logo left, and adding margin to the #nav will do the trick.

```css
#logo { float: left; }
#nav {margin-top: 80px; width: 100%; display: inline-block; }
h1.title { clear: left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Inline-Block is what I'd use with absolute positioned nav, but you have a generic `div {position:inline;}` that applies to everything on the page inside of a div. You should be more specific for your logo and nav and just get rid of the generic  styling by giving each  a class like `<div class="WHATEVER">` so you can target the div you want to work on.

Then try this:

```
#logo {
    width: 240px;
    display: inline-block;

#nav buttons {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;}
```